# How to change all purple color during login?

Tags: gnome, login, 17.10, gdm

I changed the default color of GDM on Ubuntu 17.10 to grey, changed the plymouth theme to spinner from plymouth-themes, and changed the grub background to my liking.

Still, after I type my password in GDM, when the system goes to the desktop, for a second I see purple colored display. How can I change that background?

Comment: Could you share how you change the GDM color and the plymouth theme? I want to set the backgrounds of them, but don't know how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is the default desktop color showing while your wallpaper is loaded.

You should be able to change the desktop color in the control panel.

Comment: Didn't find any options for that. Did try gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid' didn't work either. Thank you anyway, now I know what to look for

Comment: Could you add more details about how to do that?

Comment: @wjandrea the exact details depends on DE being used. I don't use Unity. If someone has specific detail please add it.

Comment: @ravery OK. OP is running 17.10, so it's probably safe to assume they're using Gnome.

Comment: @wjandrea -- yes and probably Wayland. OS states installing gnome-session fixed it. Not sure how, but I assume it removed the delay.

Comment: @ravery gnome session sets the default background color for the login session to dark grey/black, this is why they think it fixed it, the flash to a complete different color does not happen and its easier on the eyes.

Comment: @Videonauth -- thank you, then in this case it did fix it, as that flash is what he wanted removed/changed

Answer (score 3):

In the end I installed `gnome-session` and it fixed the problem.